# ios Permission Denied" prompt after app launches successfully

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm getting an error that states "Permission Denied" after my app launches on simulator or testing devices.  The app compiles without errors, then launches, then on my "home" screen I get a "Permission Denied" alert to pop up with only an Exit button.   I have tried a rebooting, cleaning the project, resetting simulator data and recreating the project.  I have also refreshed my certs, provisioning profiles etc from "Organizer".

I can successfully open other archived versions of the same project.  One odd thing to note... I received a weird prompt from a testing device about installing from a trusted source (or something similar,can't remember the exact wording). I didn't think anything of it, and I "allowed" it the source or whatever.  Since then, I've gotten this error, what could be causing this???  If it matters, I'm using Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

> after my app launches

Any alert shown after your app launches indicates it is originating from your code. Search for that string in your code base, or any alerts and look for where you may be displaying overly generic or non-specific error messages.

Comment: It turns out it was a third-party vendor handling our distribution.  Appblade has this functionality baked in, which is why the app would successfully build and launch.  Just in case someone else has this issue...

Comment: @user2448055 Yes, you are absolutely correct! AppBlade was the culprit! It wasted my 2 days! I will complain about this.